# Device to remove condensate, without creating a hazard (EX) zone

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pipelines, safety, valves

I have gas pipeline with biogas, low pressure - approx 40mbar over atmosphere. I want to remove a small amount of condensate, inside a building, without creating an [ex-zone](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hazardous-areas-classification-d_395.html). Small amount: I honestly don't know but it should be next to nothing. But I create a low point and want to be sure I don't block my pipeline.

What is a valve that I can build into the pipeline at the low point, that allows me to ex-filtrate gas without creating an ex-zone?

No need for an actual supplier, but some terms to aid my googling my writing of the RFQ would be great. Plus the technical info to decide if it's the right gadget for my problem!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term ex-zone, but upon googling it seems you are referring to the European classification for hazardous areas.  I've added a link to the question for others who might be unfamiliar.

Comment: The important thing is that the device is reliably gas-tight in both directions (reliably in the eyes of the certifying body).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [swimmer operated condensate traps](http://mankenberg.de/en/20/prgb:7/product:kondensatableiter-schwimmergesteuert/produkte.html) (link contains cut view). The operating principle seems fairly simple, a swimmer in the pot opens a valve when enough condensate has accumulated and closes before the pot is empty. The specific product I linked has been accepted as tight enough for not creating an ex-zone, I'm sure there's others.

Note: I don't want to advertise for Mankenberg, it's just the first example I found.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you can mark it as the correct answer.